# in Typescript, how do I determine the return type of a function based on a parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In Typescript, I want to determine the return type of a function based on its arguments. In the example below, if `getPropsForComponentKey` is called with an argument of type `ComponentKey.A`, its return type should be `AProps`. I should be able to use control flow analysis to guard against returning a value with an incompatible type. However, I'm not sure how to describe the type of this function such that it expects `AProps` to be returned when 'A' is passed in.

I tried to use a generic type, `T`, and use it to index into an indexed access type, `PropTypesForComponentKey`, so that the return type will resolve to either `AProps` or `BProps`, depending on what is passed into the function. The compiler error indicates that `AProps` is not assignable to `PropTypesForComponentKey[T]`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-a59wOfDLhYoRqCobbyYAyXpz-ufH0nggyaXQKcNGBUJwESPR2PCuEkBEaGRVEoGlWBWiqL8n3FUx5yDRoPy-L8K1-HA8WkORFCbElXDJClOEg7hv0rYV6DXdogA)

```js
type AProps = {
  value: number;
}

type BProps = {
  description: string;
}

enum ComponentKey {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
}

type PropTypesForComponentKey  = {
  [ComponentKey.A]: AProps;
  [ComponentKey.B]: BProps;
}

// this object enforces the mapping between key and value types
const propsForComponentKey: PropTypesForComponentKey = {
  [ComponentKey.A]: { value: 3 },
  [ComponentKey.B]: { description: 'foo' },
}

// we know that aProp is of type AProps when we use 'A' as an index into propsForComponentKey
const aProp = propsForComponentKey['A'];

// How do I enforce the return type of this function?
function getPropsForComponentKey<T extends ComponentKey>(componentKey: T): null | PropTypesForComponentKey[T] {
  switch(componentKey) {
    case ComponentKey.A:
      return { value:  3 } as AProps;
    case ComponentKey.B:
      return { description: 'foo' };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get this behaviour using control flow analysis. Though, you get the same result by using function overloads. This is a bit more verbose but gets the job done.

```js
function getPropsForComponentKey(componentKey: ComponentKey.A): AProps
function getPropsForComponentKey(componentKey: ComponentKey.B): BProps
function getPropsForComponentKey(componentKey: string): null
function getPropsForComponentKey(componentKey: ComponentKey | string): null | AProps | BProps {
  switch(componentKey) {
    case ComponentKey.A:
      return { value:  3 } as AProps
      
    case ComponentKey.B:
      return { description: 'foo' } as BProps;
  }
  return null;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-RSKRg-bhY7nW9Y9HDXU497c8CAD5QDRaJM0FOkKBl8oiOuBxug1DbeTAGS9GMFz4WxwEAgyYioaCm7EwKhOQdQPkCoU4eGUGjI1FQEewG0zgjTqDD0dF3vQgRT7ez-mC4Vw-FyRSqkmuMkUzjr9BCZ5VVFOOeXujkVPtLc9wTCsFTWs8LhZhGLrFvYerjtClpAbQDxME8KA0O+jZYFBIiRrB+oIQ0-rIQ8tBIH0ibVv+tY4eGeEwUecGPkg5IWkAA)

Comment: Note that this does not enforce the return type. TypeScript does not enforce overloads

Comment: function overload is indeed currently the best option for your case, see https://dev.to/pffigueiredo/the-typescript-functions-mental-model-1301

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have made it clear that the more important feature of this function type is for it to enforce the return type.